# Sending numbers from Pure Data - numbers adding up instead of staying separate

Tags: python, python-sockets, puredata

I've got a very simple set up in Pure Data: it creates a local host socket and sends a number through this socket. The number comes either from a Vslider or a Number box.

[Pure Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7SZ8V.png)

This data is then received in Python through the Socket module. It is decoded and converted to float(), thereafter the float value is printed.

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_address = ('localhost', 13001)
sock.bind(server_address)
sock.listen(1)

while True:
    connection, client_address = sock.accept()

    try:
        while True:
            data = connection.recv(16)
            data = data.decode("utf-8")
            data = data.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\r', '').replace(';', '')
            VARIABLE = float(data)
            print(f'received {VARIABLE} as a float')
    finally:
        connection.close()
```

The problem is that when I move the Vslider **too quickly** (or when I move the mouse cursor in the number box too quickly). The number values sent from Pd are "**appended**" together. For instance, I go very quickly from 1 to 10. Values 1-6 are correctly decoded and printed. However, values 7-10 are not printed separately, instead being printed as 78910. This can happen with any values up to 10 numbers or so. So I could get 12345678910111213 and so on. I'm fairly new to Pd so I'm not sure at all where this error originated.

[python output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vI5dR.png)

Comment: Doesn't `.replace('\n', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\r', '').replace(';', '')` toss away delimiters that would be useful in distinguishing the chunks of data being sent?

Comment: is there any specific reason to provide the `python output` as an image (it is pure text)?

Answer (score 0):

there are two (related) problems:

1. TCP/IP is a serial protocol. there is no guarantee whatsoever that data sent in one go, will appear on the other side as a single "packet" (there is no notion of "packets" in TCP/IP).
   this means that it is possible that your code receives a single message in multiple `connection.recv()` invocations, or vice versa. you should therefore reassemble the buffers before processing them.
2. Pd uses [FUDI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FUDI) as the native application layer protocol, which uses the semicolon (`;`) as the delimiter between messages (so it is possible to reconstruct the various messages from the TCP/IP data stream). you are just throwing away this delimiter, rather than use it.

so there are two fixes to your problem:

1. do not limit the receiving buffer to 16 bytes. just ask for much more, and you can usually ignore segmentation.
2. split the received data at the `;`

like this:

```py
        while True:
            # receive a large buffer
            data = connection.recv(65535)
            data = data.decode("utf-8")
            # split a message boundaries
            for d in data.split(";"):
                # ignore line-feeds and the like
                d = d.strip()
                if not d:
                    continue
                VARIABLE = float(d)
                print(f"received {VARIABLE} as a float")
```